# How to generate a 3D grid of vectors ? (each position in the 3D grid is a vector)

Tags: python, numpy, vector, grid, numpy-ndarray

I want to generate a four dimensional array with dimensions (dim,N,N,N). The first component ndim =3 and N corresponds to the grid length. How can one elegantly generate such an array using python ?

here is my 'ugly' implementation:

```
qvec=np.zeros([ndim,N,N,N])  

freq   = np.arange(-(N-1)/2.,+(N+1)/2.)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(freq[range(N)], freq[range(N)], freq[range(N)],indexing='ij')

qvec[0,:,:,:]=x
qvec[1,:,:,:]=y
qvec[2,:,:,:]=z
```

Comment: Doesn't look *ugly* to me. Why do you think so?

Comment: @kmario23 i did not like writing qvec thrice. I thought maybe there is a 'one-liner' or another function that could generate this directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation looks good enough to me. However, here are some improvements to make it prettier:

```
qvec=np.empty([ndim,N,N,N])  

freq   = np.arange(-(N-1)/2.,+(N+1)/2.)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[freq]*ndim, indexing='ij')

qvec[0,...]=x   # qvec[0] = x
qvec[1,...]=y   # qvec[1] = y
qvec[2,...]=z   # qvec[2] = z
```

The improvements are:

- Using `numpy.empty()` instead of `numpy.zeros()`
- Getting rid of the `range(N)` indexing since that would give the same `freq` array
- Using iterable unpacking and utilizing `ndim`
- Using the *ellipsis* notation for dimensions (this is also not needed)

So, after incorporating all of the above points, the below piece of code would suffice:

```
qvec=np.empty([ndim,N,N,N])  
freq   = np.arange(-(N-1)/2.,+(N+1)/2.)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[freq]*ndim, indexing='ij')    
qvec[0:ndim] = x, y, z
```

Note: I'm assuming `N` is same since you used same variable name.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It does look pretty right now :). Yes N is the same.

Comment: how exactly does *[freq]*ndim work ?I have usually seen *a on the left-hand side but not sure how this works here.

Comment: `[freq]*3`  is equivalent to `[freq, freq, freq]`. It just repeats the inside element that many times, here 3. Using a `*` at the front unpacks these elements (i.e. it removes the `list` since that's what `numpy.meshgrid` needs. HTH :)